# pyspark dataframe inside a for loop

Tags: apache-spark, for-loop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a situation as below. I have a master dataframe DF1. I am processing inside a for-loop to reflect the changes and my pseudo codes are as below.

```
for Year in [2019, 2020]:
  query_west = query_{Year}
  df_west = spark.sql(query_west)
  df_final = DF1.join(df_west, on['ID'], how='left')
```

In this case df_final is getting joined with query and getting updated every iteration right? I want that changes to be reflected happening on my main dataframe DF1 every iteration inside the for loop.

Please let me know whether my logic is right. Thanks.

Comment: unless you have `df1 = df_final` after 3rd now, you will be creating `df_final` each iteration and you will only have latest result at the end of loop

Comment: OK Thanks. Should I add `df1 = df_final` as 4th line in my code inside the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment by @venky__ suggested, you need to add another line `DF1 = df_final` at the end of the for loop, in order to make sure DF1 is updated in each iteration.

Another way is to use `reduce` to combine the joins all at once. e.g.

```
from functools import reduce

dfs = [DF1]
for Year in [2019, 2020]:
  query_west = f'query_{Year}'
  df_west = spark.sql(query_west)
  dfs.append(df_west)

df_final = reduce(lambda x, y: x.join(y, 'ID', 'left'), dfs)
```

which is equivalent to

```
df_final = DF1.join(spark.sql('query_2019'), 'ID', 'left').join(spark.sql('query_2020'), 'ID', 'left')
```